# Loading text file data into JTextfield

Tags: java, swing, arraylist, jtextfield

I have been searching through various tutorials for two days in order to finish this code, however none of them actually help me to understand the concept of what is wrong with my code.

I'm attempting to write to a text file, and then read from it into a Jtable. I'm using arrays. My instructor has told me that I was using too many lists- so I tried to use only the one 'constructorList' and now it won't compile.

The error that shows up is:

```
error: method readFile in class CQUPestGUI cannot be applied to given types;

        readFile();
required: ArrayList<String>
found: no arguments
reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
1 error
```

Any attempts to correct it on my part only seem to make it worse.

This is the section of code that seems to be related to the error.

```
 private void buttonLoadStoredContractsActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                          
        readFile();
}
```

I've skipped some sections in order not to give a lot of code to read through

```
protected void readFile(ArrayList<String> listContractors)
{
   BufferedReader reader = null;
   //ArrayList showContract = new ArrayList();

   try
   {
       reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("Pest.txt"));
       String nLine = reader.readLine();


       while (nLine != null)
       {
           listContractors.add(nLine);
           String [] rows = nLine.split("-");
           for (String s: rows)
           {
                System.out.println(s);
           }
           nLine = reader.readLine();
       }
   }
   catch (FileNotFoundException e)
   {
       e.printStackTrace();
   }
   catch (IOException e)
   {
        e.printStackTrace();
   }
   displayStoredContracts(listContractors);
}

protected void displayStoredContracts(ArrayList<String> listContractors)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < listContractors.size(); i++)
    {
        txtAreaSavedContracts.append((String) listContractors.get(i));


    }
}
```

And if anyone *does* want to see the entire code, here it is in pastebin -- [full code](http://pastebin.com/74buZXL0). I use the gui builder, since I'm just a beginner and with deadlines to meet- so a lot of this will be messy. I'm only putting it up in case it's wanted.

Comment: Do you need to save the contractors in an ArrayList? If not, then take out the ArrayList<String> listContractors parameter from the readFile method. If you do need to save them, then consider making listContractors a private member of your class and work with the member list instead of passing a parameter to the readFile method.

Comment: *"I have tried and tried to do this for days, and I really feel like giving up."* Don't give up before asking a question! Speaking of which: You've described a requirement or specification, but asked no question. What is your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is very easy to find, your method signature says that, the method `protected void readFile(ArrayList<String> listContractors)` only accepts a `java.util.ArrayList` of `String` type. But when you call the method, you do not pass any parameter, you call the method by `readFile();`. You should have passed an ArrayList as method parameter.

1. Create a `ArrayList<String> list= new ArrayList<String>();`
2. Add some elements: `list.add("asd");` (as you require)
3. Call the method: `readFile(list)`;

Hope, it helps you.

N.B. I do not think the definition of the method `readFile` is correct. It should not have that `ArrayList<String>` as formal parameter. It must create an instance of this `ArrayList` within the method block and add element to it within the method boundary.

Comment: Initializing the array list outside the methods seems to have resolved the error.